# Exporting the current page to pdf in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I wanna export the current web page to pdf and I did as follows by using the `JSPDF`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.min.js"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            function getPDF()
            {

                html2canvas(document.body,{

                    onrendered: function(canvas)
                    {
                    var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                    var doc = new jsPDF();
                    var width = doc.internal.pageSize.width;    
                    var height = doc.internal.pageSize.height;


                    doc.setFont("helvetica");
                    doc.setFontType("bold");
                    doc.setFontSize(9);


                    alert(width)
                    alert(height)
                  //  pdf.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 0, 0,width,height);
                doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 0, 0,width,height);
                    doc.save("test.pdf");
                    }
                }

                );
            }


        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="dv" style="margin-top:120px">
        <span style="float:right">

            <input type="button" name="btn" id="btn" value="Download-pdf" onclick="getPDF();"/>
        </span><br><br>
        <table width="100%" border='1' style="text-align:center;border-collapse:collapse">

        <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th> Row ddddd </th>
                    <th> Row ddddd </th>
                    <th> Row ddddd </th>
                    <th> Row ddddd </th>
                    <th> Row ddddd </th>
                    <th> Row ddddd </th><th> Row ddddd </th><th> Row ddddd </th>


                </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>

            </tr><tr>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>

            </tr><tr>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>

            </tr><tr>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>

            </tr><tr>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>

            </tr><tr>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>

            </tr><tr>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>

            </tr><tr>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>

            </tr><tr>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>

            </tr><tr>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>

            </tr><tr>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>

            </tr><tr>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>

            </tr><tr>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>

            </tr><tr>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>

            </tr><tr>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>

            </tr><tr>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>

            </tr><tr>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>

            </tr><tr>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>
            <td> Row ddddd </td><td> Row ddddd </td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>

        </div>
    </body>
```

and the browser shows the page as 
[image]

I will get the same page in pdf as 
[image]

the pdf is some what different than original one ..i need to get the exact one please any suggestions to improve the quality of the pdf and thanks in advance.

Comment: I just copy paste your code to jsfiddle. Pdf is fine. see this https://jsfiddle.net/2do0jy8v/

Comment: yeah, but the quality of pdf is low as shown in above image ..any suggestions to improve the quality

Answer (score 0):

Changed `getPDF` for a better pdf. See [addHTML source code](http://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/plugins_addhtml.js.html#line12)

```
function getPDF() {
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.addHTML(document.body, function() {
        doc.save('test.pdf')
    })
}
```